# React - render values with condition

Tags: reactjs

I have this Class Component `Field.jsx` (snippet):

```
render() {
...
<div className="field-row"> 

   {this.getPlayersByPosition(players, 5).map((player,i) => (
      <Position
        key={i} 
        className={fullScreen ? "full-screen-player" : "player"}
        getPositionData={this.getPositionData}
        toggleFullScreen={this.toggleFullScreen.bind(this)}
        fullScreen={this.state.fullScreen}
      >{player.name}</Position>
    ))} 
</div>
...
```

{

---

And I need to pass a rendering condition. The condition should be:

**When I render `Field`, I want to show only player name.**

**When I click, and `toggleFullScreen` happens, then I show all the data.**

---

This is what I'm trying:

`Position.jsx`

```
export const Position = props => {

    const { matches, mean, goals} = props.getPositionData(props.children);

    return (

        <div

           {props.fullScreen && 
            <p>Name: {props.children}</p>   // condition 
          }

            className={props.className}
            onClick={() => {
                props.getPositionData(props.children);
                props.toggleFullScreen();
            }}
        >
            <p>Name: {props.children}</p>
            <p>Goals: {goals}</p>
            <p>Mean: {mean}</p>
            <p>Matches: {matches}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
      Line 13:10:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

  11 |         <div
  12 | 
> 13 |         {props.fullScreen && 
     |          ^
  14 |      <p>Name: {props.children}</p>
  15 |          }
  16 |
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: You didn't close your `div` tag before you tried to render a p tag - get a linter

Answer (score 0):

```
{props.fullScreen && 
  <p>Name: {props.children}</p>   // condition 
}
```

These lines appear in the middle of a `<div>`, where you should be specifying the div's props. You'll need to move it down to be a child of the div.

```
<div
 className={props.className}
 onClick={() => {
     props.getPositionData(props.children);
     props.toggleFullScreen();
 }}
>
 {props.fullScreen && (
   <p>Name: {props.children}</p>
 )}
 <p>Goals: {goals}</p>
 <p>Mean: {mean}</p>
 <p>Matches: {matches}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. but the condition is not working, somehow. I still print all the data, even when not in fullScreen...any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to hide? The entire div? From the code you provided it looked like you just wanted to hide the `<p>` with the name, so that's what i replicated in my answer.

Comment: when I render Field, I want to show only player name and hide all the rest. when I click, I want to show all the data.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer, sorry for the confusion.